# Open XML SDK - image not showing in excel

Tags: openxml-sdk

I'm able to successfully create a spreadsheet, and I appear to have added the image via code, the problem is that when I open the spreadsheet, there is no image. Here is my code:

```
    public static void CreateSpreadsheetWorkbook(string filepath)
    {
        SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(filepath, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);

        WorkbookPart workbookpart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
        workbookpart.Workbook = new Workbook();

        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookpart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
        worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

        Sheets sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());
        Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart), SheetId = 1, Name = "mySheet" };
        sheets.Append(sheet);

        string sImagePath = @"C:\temp\install_button.png";
        DrawingsPart drawingsPart = worksheetPart.AddNewPart<DrawingsPart>();

        ImagePart imagePart = drawingsPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Png, worksheetPart.GetIdOfPart(drawingsPart));
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(sImagePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            imagePart.FeedData(stream);
        }

        workbookpart.Workbook.Save();
        spreadsheetDocument.Close();
    }
```

Thanks

Stu

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally when I can't figure out why something doesn't work when dealing with the Open XML SDK I use the [Open XML SDK 2.0 Productivity Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c6e744e5-36e9-45f5-8d8c-331df206e0d0&displaylang=en) to figure out what the code should be. I will normally create a blank worksheet in Excel, add a picture and then save the document. Then I will open that document in the Productivity tool and click the Reflect code button to see how to recreate that document. I did that to see how to answer your question and got the following code to create a worksheet part:

```
        // Adds child parts and generates content of the specified part.
        public void CreateWorksheetPart(WorksheetPart part)
        {
            DrawingsPart drawingsPart1 = part.AddNewPart<DrawingsPart>("rId2");
            GenerateDrawingsPart1Content(drawingsPart1);

            ImagePart imagePart1 = drawingsPart1.AddNewPart<ImagePart>("image/png", "rId1");
            GenerateImagePart1Content(imagePart1);

            SpreadsheetPrinterSettingsPart spreadsheetPrinterSettingsPart1 = part.AddNewPart<SpreadsheetPrinterSettingsPart>("rId1");
            GenerateSpreadsheetPrinterSettingsPart1Content(spreadsheetPrinterSettingsPart1);

            GeneratePartContent(part);
        }

        // Generates content of drawingsPart1.
        private void GenerateDrawingsPart1Content(DrawingsPart drawingsPart1)
        {
            Xdr.WorksheetDrawing worksheetDrawing1 = new Xdr.WorksheetDrawing();
            worksheetDrawing1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("xdr", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/spreadsheetDrawing");
            worksheetDrawing1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("a", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main");

            Xdr.TwoCellAnchor twoCellAnchor1 = new Xdr.TwoCellAnchor(){ EditAs = Xdr.EditAsValues.OneCell };

            Xdr.FromMarker fromMarker1 = new Xdr.FromMarker();
            Xdr.ColumnId columnId1 = new Xdr.ColumnId();
            columnId1.Text = "0";
            Xdr.ColumnOffset columnOffset1 = new Xdr.ColumnOffset();
            columnOffset1.Text = "0";
            Xdr.RowId rowId1 = new Xdr.RowId();
            rowId1.Text = "0";
            Xdr.RowOffset rowOffset1 = new Xdr.RowOffset();
            rowOffset1.Text = "0";

            fromMarker1.Append(columnId1);
            fromMarker1.Append(columnOffset1);
            fromMarker1.Append(rowId1);
            fromMarker1.Append(rowOffset1);

            Xdr.ToMarker toMarker1 = new Xdr.ToMarker();
            Xdr.ColumnId columnId2 = new Xdr.ColumnId();
            columnId2.Text = "0";
            Xdr.ColumnOffset columnOffset2 = new Xdr.ColumnOffset();
            columnOffset2.Text = "171429";
            Xdr.RowId rowId2 = new Xdr.RowId();
            rowId2.Text = "0";
            Xdr.RowOffset rowOffset2 = new Xdr.RowOffset();
            rowOffset2.Text = "171429";

            toMarker1.Append(columnId2);
            toMarker1.Append(columnOffset2);
            toMarker1.Append(rowId2);
            toMarker1.Append(rowOffset2);

            Xdr.Picture picture1 = new Xdr.Picture();

            Xdr.NonVisualPictureProperties nonVisualPictureProperties1 = new Xdr.NonVisualPictureProperties();
            Xdr.NonVisualDrawingProperties nonVisualDrawingProperties1 = new Xdr.NonVisualDrawingProperties(){ Id = (UInt32Value)2U, Name = "Picture 1", Description = "eprs_reports_arrow.png" };

            Xdr.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties nonVisualPictureDrawingProperties1 = new Xdr.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties();
            A.PictureLocks pictureLocks1 = new A.PictureLocks(){ NoChangeAspect = true };

            nonVisualPictureDrawingProperties1.Append(pictureLocks1);

            nonVisualPictureProperties1.Append(nonVisualDrawingProperties1);
            nonVisualPictureProperties1.Append(nonVisualPictureDrawingProperties1);

            Xdr.BlipFill blipFill1 = new Xdr.BlipFill();

            A.Blip blip1 = new A.Blip(){ Embed = "rId1", CompressionState = A.BlipCompressionValues.Print };
            blip1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("r", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships");

            A.Stretch stretch1 = new A.Stretch();
            A.FillRectangle fillRectangle1 = new A.FillRectangle();

            stretch1.Append(fillRectangle1);

            blipFill1.Append(blip1);
            blipFill1.Append(stretch1);

            Xdr.ShapeProperties shapeProperties1 = new Xdr.ShapeProperties();

            A.Transform2D transform2D1 = new A.Transform2D();
            A.Offset offset1 = new A.Offset(){ X = 0L, Y = 0L };
            A.Extents extents1 = new A.Extents(){ Cx = 171429L, Cy = 171429L };

            transform2D1.Append(offset1);
            transform2D1.Append(extents1);

            A.PresetGeometry presetGeometry1 = new A.PresetGeometry(){ Preset = A.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle };
            A.AdjustValueList adjustValueList1 = new A.AdjustValueList();

            presetGeometry1.Append(adjustValueList1);

            shapeProperties1.Append(transform2D1);
            shapeProperties1.Append(presetGeometry1);

            picture1.Append(nonVisualPictureProperties1);
            picture1.Append(blipFill1);
            picture1.Append(shapeProperties1);
            Xdr.ClientData clientData1 = new Xdr.ClientData();

            twoCellAnchor1.Append(fromMarker1);
            twoCellAnchor1.Append(toMarker1);
            twoCellAnchor1.Append(picture1);
            twoCellAnchor1.Append(clientData1);

            worksheetDrawing1.Append(twoCellAnchor1);

            drawingsPart1.WorksheetDrawing = worksheetDrawing1;
        }

        // Generates content of imagePart1.
        private void GenerateImagePart1Content(ImagePart imagePart1)
        {
            System.IO.Stream data = GetBinaryDataStream(imagePart1Data);
            imagePart1.FeedData(data);
            data.Close();
        }

        // Generates content of spreadsheetPrinterSettingsPart1.
        private void GenerateSpreadsheetPrinterSettingsPart1Content(SpreadsheetPrinterSettingsPart spreadsheetPrinterSettingsPart1)
        {
            System.IO.Stream data = GetBinaryDataStream(spreadsheetPrinterSettingsPart1Data);
            spreadsheetPrinterSettingsPart1.FeedData(data);
            data.Close();
        }

        // Generates content of part.
        private void GeneratePartContent(WorksheetPart part)
        {
            Worksheet worksheet1 = new Worksheet();
            worksheet1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("r", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships");
            SheetDimension sheetDimension1 = new SheetDimension(){ Reference = "A1" };

            SheetViews sheetViews1 = new SheetViews();
            SheetView sheetView1 = new SheetView(){ TabSelected = true, WorkbookViewId = (UInt32Value)0U };

            sheetViews1.Append(sheetView1);
            SheetFormatProperties sheetFormatProperties1 = new SheetFormatProperties(){ DefaultRowHeight = 15D };
            SheetData sheetData1 = new SheetData();
            PageMargins pageMargins1 = new PageMargins(){ Left = 0.7D, Right = 0.7D, Top = 0.75D, Bottom = 0.75D, Header = 0.3D, Footer = 0.3D };
            PageSetup pageSetup1 = new PageSetup(){ Orientation = OrientationValues.Portrait, Id = "rId1" };
            Drawing drawing1 = new Drawing(){ Id = "rId2" };

            worksheet1.Append(sheetDimension1);
            worksheet1.Append(sheetViews1);
            worksheet1.Append(sheetFormatProperties1);
            worksheet1.Append(sheetData1);
            worksheet1.Append(pageMargins1);
            worksheet1.Append(pageSetup1);
            worksheet1.Append(drawing1);

            part.Worksheet = worksheet1;
        }

        #region Binary Data
        private string imagePart1Data ="lots of binary data here";

        private System.IO.Stream GetBinaryDataStream(string base64String)
        {
            return new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64String));
        }

        #endregion
```

I recommend you do the same with your image and play around with the generated code in order to get it to work since as you can see just adding one picture to a new slide is a lot of code.

Comment: Amazing did not know about the Productivity Tool, thank you!